# Find matching predicate and using iterable.tryFind return the element from the list in java

Tags: java, guava

I have a list and I want an element from the list which matches a predicate. I am finding an element from the list which matches the first predicate, if the first predicate does not return true, it matches with the second predicate.

Here is an example:

Case1:

```
result = iterable.tryFind(List, Predicates.or(predicate1, predicate2)).orNull();
```

The issue with this piece of code is it finds the first element which matches any of those predicates. Even if the second element in the list is matching the first predicate, which in my case should be given higher priority.In this case, I am expecting the result here as a second element, but getting first element (as it is the first element which is matching one of those predicates).

Case2:

```
result = iterable.tryFind(List, Predicates.and(predicate1, predicate2)).orNull();
```

This will obviously not work, if the first predicate returns false.

Case 3:

```
result = iterable.tryFind(List, predicate1).orNull();

if(result == null)
result = iterable.tryFind(List, predicate2).orNull();
```

This will work for me, but it looks messy and defeats the purpose of functional programming.

Is there any other way to fetch an element from a list that will work for my scenario ?

Comment: Does it actually defeat the purpose just because you have branches? What's bothering you: the branch, the double iteration, something else? You can get the result with a single iteration, by mapping instead of filtering, so you know which predicate matched, filtering the elements which didn't match any predicate and then reducing to keep the first match, with the precedence given to the match from the first predicate. Is it really going to be less messy (in Java)?

Comment: @FrankPavageau : branches are bothering me. I expected it to work without separating the predicates. The one you are suggesting will be similar to this, if I understood it right.I guess this is the only way I can make it work.

Comment: I don't think "functional programming" means removing all control flow: something has to do it at some point, and when you filter a collection it's just hidden in the method, not removed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Optional.or` instead of `Predicate.or` to get what you want:

```
result = Iterables.tryFind(list, predicate1)
         .or(Iterables.tryFind(list, predicate2))
         .orNull();
```

Comment: The problem is that `Iterables.tryFind(list, predicate2)` gets always evaluated. You'd need `||` from Javascript or `or` from LISP. In Java it could only work if `tryFind` was lazy and `Optional` would evaluate its argument when needed.

Comment: This is the disadvantage of my solution. The lazy `tryFind` could be implemented with a `Supplier`, but this does only work if it doesn't return `absent`.